# Simple example of Postgres query in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql

For the life of me I can't find a simple example of just running something like

`"SELECT * FROM MyTable"`

in Ruby.  Everything I'm finding assumes an ORM or Rails.  For now, I don't want ORM; I don't want Rails.  I'm looking for something standalone that uses the pg gem and executes a simple query.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I tried to find the answer by googling but all documentation I could find apparently assumes I already know how to use ruby-pg.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the pg gem documentation (http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.10.0/frames)

```
require 'pg'
conn = PGconn.open(:dbname => 'test')
res  = conn.exec('SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c')
res.getvalue(0,0) # '1'
res[0]['b']       # '2'
res[0]['c']       # nil
```

My next question would be authentication with a DB that requires a password. 
Looks like you can send a connection string like this:
`PGconn.connect( "dbname=test password=mypass")`
or use the constuctor with parameters:
`PGconn.new(host, port, options, tty, dbname, login, password)` or use a hash like `:password => '...'` see [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.10.0/PGconn#initialize-instance_method) for all available options.

Comment: Good simple example, thanks. I'm experienced with PostgreSQL via psql, python, Java and Perl but had never used Ruby, and this made it trivial to verify that my Pg gem installation was fine. Appreciated.

Comment: How do I print this result in a table, like it is in the pgadmin gui tool ?

Comment: The 'pg' gem has changed since this answer was accepted, and the above example no longer works with more current versions. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338630/how-to-connect-the-ruby-to-the-postgresql

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.connect("ip adddress", 5432, '', '', "db name", "user", "password")
res  = conn.exec('select tablename, tableowner from pg_tables')

res.each do |row|
  puts row['tablename'] + ' | ' + row['tableowner']
end
```

Comment: Looks like this uses the 'postgres' gem which has been superceded by the 'pg' gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/postgres

Comment: How do I print this result in a table, like it is in the pgadmin gui tool ?

Comment: I edited the answer to be a little more clear. You are getting an array of hashes back, so you can output it any way you like. The above example will print rows of "tablename | owner".

Answer (score 5):

For the newer versions (e.g., 0.18.3 up to the current latest version 0.21.0) of gem pg , instead of using:

```
conn = PGconn.connect(*args)
```

(The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
removed as of version 1.0.)

You should use `conn = PG.connect(*args)`, for example:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect("IP-Address", 5432, '', '', "database-name", "username", "password")
res = conn.exec('select product_id, description, price from product')

res.each do |row|
    puts row
end
```

Reference link: [gem pg](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/)

Answer (score 2):

I put together an example that will work if you have Docker, ruby, and the pg gem installed:

```
db=pgexample

docker rm -f $db &> /dev/null
docker run -itd --name $db -p 4242:5432 postgres:10

sleep 3 # wait for postgres to start

docker exec -u postgres $db psql -c "
    CREATE TABLE things (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar (50) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES ('foo');
    INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES ('bar');
    INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES ('baz');
"

docker exec -u postgres $db psql -c 'SELECT * FROM things;'
#  id | name
# ----+------
#   1 | foo
#   2 | bar
#   3 | baz
# (3 rows)

ruby <<EOF
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'postgres', host: 'localhost', user: 'postgres', port: 4242)
q = ARGV.first || 'SELECT * FROM things;'
p conn.exec(q).to_a
EOF
# [{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"foo"}, {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"bar"}, {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"baz"}]

docker rm -f $db
```

Answer (score 2):

In new versions you need to use `PG::Connection` instead of `PGconn`

It works like this:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG::Connection.open(dbname: 'test')

res = conn.exec_params('SELECT $1 AS a, $2 AS b, $3 AS c', [1, 2, nil])
res = conn.exec('SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, NULL AS c')
```

See pg docs: https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html

Answer (score 0):

## November 2023 update:

Assuming you're using the [`pg`](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg) gem:

```ruby
require 'pg'

pg_connection = PG::Connection.new(host: 'localhost', user: 'postgres', password: 'postgres')

# The examples below assume the following SQL schema:
# CREATE TABLE users (id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name varchar);
# INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('john'), ('bruce'), ('william'), ('sarah');

# Inserts new row and prints its ID
new_username = 'new'
pg_result = pg_connection.exec_params('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id', [new_username])
puts "Inserted record's id: #{pg_result.getvalue(0, 0)}"

# Prints existing rows
pg_result = pg_connection.exec('SELECT * FROM users')

pg_result.each do |row|
  puts "Fetched record details: id: #{row['id']}, name: #{row['name']}"
end
```

The code gives the following output:

```
Inserted record's id: 5
Fetched record details: id: 1, name: john
Fetched record details: id: 2, name: bruce
Fetched record details: id: 3, name: william
Fetched record details: id: 4, name: sarah
Fetched record details: id: 5, name: new
```