# How to Connect the Ruby to the Postgresql?

Tags: ruby

I try to connect The ruby to the postgres, but it cannot connecting ,it shows an error `"uninitialized constant PGconn"`.

```
require "pg"
conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, "", "", "test1")
res = conn.exec("select * from a;")
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: uninitialize constant  PGconn

Comment: Where did you see this name, PGconn?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658702/ruby-postgresql-tutorials

Comment: Ha, next time use slightly more recent answers. Not ones from 7 years ago. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PGConn is wrong, the postrges gem called pg is using PG now.

Example:

```
require 'pg' 
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'sales' ) 
conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity" ) do |result| 
    result.each do |row| 
        puts row.values_at('procpid', 'usename', 'current_query')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

```ruby
require 'pg'

pg_connection = PG::Connection.new(host: 'localhost', user: 'postgres', password: 'postgres')
```

[`Connection.new` documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#new-class_method).